# Loading GNU ld script with dlopen

Tags: c++, gnu, ld

I have an C++14 code that should load an arbitrary shared object file with `dlopen`. Unfortunately on some systems (e.g. my archlinux, reportedly also applies to some .so on ubuntu and gentoo), these so-files can be "GNU ld scripts" instead of the actual binaries.

For reference, here is the content of my `/usr/lib/libm.so`:

```
/* GNU ld script
*/
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
GROUP ( /usr/lib/libm.so.6  AS_NEEDED ( /usr/lib/libmvec.so.1 ) )
```

I have found a couple of code-pieces that deal with this issue in [ghc](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/attachment/ticket/2615/T2615a.dsend) or [ruby](https://github.com/aniederl/ffi/commit/0daa68069bf2521793025cb5b1acf47659edad24). I would like to avoid resorting to manually parsing the text file based parsing the `dlerror` text and the file. I feel that is terribly evil and I won't be able to implement and maintain corner cases of this format.

Is there a clean way to implement handling this case? Frankly I am puzzled as to why `dlopen` does not actually handle these tranparaently.

Note: Considering the aforementioned patches I think this is not simply an issue with my system configuration / versions. If this should work out-of-the-box with `dlopen` (bug instead of missing feature), please let me know.

Comment: Is your ld.so recent enough ?

Comment: Not related to a specific language, but about loading/linking.

Comment: @Olaf I am looking for a solution that I can use in my C++ program. Since I am loading the library during runtime using C++/C code, I consider this related.

Comment: @Zulan, I understand that you need to use `dlopen()` which is a [tag:c] function, but please don't write C++/C as if they where a single language with different features.

Comment: @marcolz: I have an `/usr/lib/ld-2.22.so` as part of archlinux `glibc 2.22-3`

Comment: @iharob: I never meant to imply that. I am fine anything that I can easily use in C++, which means either a clean plain C solution or a C++ specific solution.

Comment: @Olaf: I guess you removed the tags `C` and `C++`. This is however a question about how to open these .so files from within `C++`, which happens to have the same solution in `C`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linker scripts are intended to be used by the linker, not the run-time linker.

The `GNU ld script` comment should have been a giveaway: this is for `ld`, not for `ld.so`. ;-)

See for instance: http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html

So I guess using this with `dlopen()` would mean mimicking/importing part of `ld`'s magic for this, which would confirm your fears about resorting to manually parsing the text and maintaining terribly evil code.

EDIT: There seems to be one thing that can help you though:

https://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2011-07/msg00152.html

`<gnu/lib-names.h>` should contain a define LIBM_SO which should point you to the correct file that you can actually dlopen().

That means that normally no evil code would be necessary.

Comment: While this was not what I was hoping / looking for, the edit is really helpful. While it doesn't handle the issue transparently, and moves the solution to the caller code, it is clean and saves me from the horrors.